# 'undefined is not a function' from breeze insides, during basic setup

Tags: breeze

I assume it's extremely basic problem, but it caught me for two days, with no solution yet.

I'm creating a project with breeze, wrapped in requirejs, but I don't think that's the problem.

libraries loaded in dependencies are `jquery`, `q`, and `datajs`

```
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances({ dataService: "OData" });
var manager = new breeze.EntityManger('todo/Todos')
```

error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` is thrown in second line above.

breeze.EntityManager is defined for sure, exception is thrown somewhere depeer in that function, stack trace from chrome below:

```
fire jquery.js?b=1394184954069:2913
self.add jquery.js?b=1394184954069:2959
jQuery.fn.jQuery.ready jquery.js?b=1394184954069:242
jQuery.fn.jQuery.init jquery.js?b=1394184954069:185
jQuery jquery.js?b=1394184954069:63
(anonymous function) main.coffee:186
context.execCb require.js:1635
Module.check require.js:871
(anonymous function) require.js:1112
(anonymous function) require.js:129
(anonymous function) require.js:1155
each require.js:57
Module.emit require.js:1154
Module.check require.js:925
(anonymous function) require.js:1112
(anonymous function) require.js:129
(anonymous function) require.js:1155
each require.js:57
Module.emit require.js:1154
Module.check require.js:925
Module.enable require.js:1142
Module.init require.js:779
callGetModule require.js:1169
context.completeLoad require.js:1549
context.onScriptLoad require.js:1656
```

Possibly there is a config line needed, I'm not aware of? Even when I removed the first line of two `breeze.config....` error is still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are spelling Manager incorrectly

Manger - a long open box or trough for horses or cattle to eat from.

Manager - a person responsible for controlling or administering all or part of a company or similar organization.

Good luck!

Comment: You sir, are correct. And I'm going to see my doctor, to check my retard level. I might have gone full retard.